# Python ImportError

Tags: python, module, importerror

```
$ bin/python src/app/utils/loader.py newTasks checkForStuff 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/python", line 135, in <module>
    execfile(__file__)
  File "src/app/utils/loader.py", line 154, in <module>
    module = __import__(args.module)
ImportError: No module named newTasks
```

from the following loader.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Runs python')
    parser.add_argument('module', metavar='module', help="the target module")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    module = __import__(args.module)
```

newTasks.py is in the same directory as loader.py. It works on my dev box, I did an svn export to staging and the above happened. Any pointers?

Only material difference I can work out is this time I'm running out of virtualenv.

EDIT:
I changed the command line to:

```
$ bin/python src/app/utils/loader.py utils.newTasks checkForStuff
```

and the module was found ok. But my next command is to call one of the module functions `checkForStuff`:

```
parser.add_argument('func',metavar='function', help="the target function name")
...
func_param = getattr(module,args.func)
```

and now it cannot find the function?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/python", line 135, in <module>
    execfile(__file__)
  File "src/app/utils/loader.py", line 156, in <module>
    func_param = getattr(module,args.func)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'checkForStuff'
```

If I go into bin/python:

```
>>> import utils.newTasks as nt
>>> nt.checkForStuff
<function checkForStuff at 0x29b2f50>
```

This is annoying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bin/python` is not the python binary on your staging machine. Check whether it inserts the scripts directory into sys.path as ordinary python does.

Comment: I thought you were right but I made a mistake when searching the sys.path list via a for loop. The src/app dir is in the path alright, so it should pick up the utils.newTasks module. Also note my edit above - only difference between my machines is that I'm running this one under virtualenv.

Comment: @user1561108: loader.py is in src/app/utils directory, not in src/app directory. utils.newTasks and newTasks are different names (it is a `__main__` gotcha in Python that the same module can be imported using different names). With ordinary python newTasks will be imported successfully given your command-line. Though you should provide the full name instead to avoid the gotcha.

Comment: see my update. If I qualify the module name it is found, but not the function belonging to it!

Comment: @user1561108: it is another issue read `__import__` docs `__import__('utils.newTasks')` might return `utils`. So you need `reduce(getattr, 'newTasks.checkForStuff'.split('.'), module)`